# How to define const as an object in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, object, constants

I have an object

```
xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.xmlhttp")
```

How can I store this object( xmlhttp Object) as a `const`?

**Example**

```
Public xmlHttp As ... = CreateObject("MSXML2.xmlhttp")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objects cannot be `Const`. Only primitive types like `Integer` can. Also, VBA does not have the notion of a read-only field. You can sort of mimic this though by using a private field in a module and a `Public Property Get Xmlhttp()` on that module.

Answer (score 2):

As Harry pointed out, Objects cannot be `Constants`.

Yet, you may consider using classes to simulate this behavior and a read-only field. See [this article on Chip Pearson's website](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx) to learn more about classes.